# Property 'self.animator' not initialized at super.init call

Tags: error-handling, init, swift2

```
import UIKit

@objc protocol SideBarDelegate{

      func sideBarDidSelectButtonAtIndex(Index:Int)

       optional func sideBarWillClose()
       optional func sideBarWillOpen()
}


class SideBar: NSObject,SideBarTableViewControllerDelegate {

       let barWidth:CGFloat = 150
       let sideBarTableViewTopInset:CGFloat = 64
       let sideBarContainerView:UIView = UIView()
       let sideBarTableViewController:SideBarTableViewController = SideBarTableViewController()
       var originView:UIView?

       var animator:UIDynamicAnimator
       var delegate:SideBarDelegate
       var isSideBarOpen:Bool = false

    override init() {

        super.init()    //ERROR ON THIS LINE
    }

    init(sourceView:UIView, menuItems:Array<String>) {


           super.init()        //ERROR ON THIS LINE
           originView = sourceView
           sideBarTableViewController.tableData = menuItems
           animator = UIDynamicAnimator(referenceView: originView!)

           setupSideBar()



             let showGestureRecognizer:UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleSwipe:")
        showGestureRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right
        originView!.addGestureRecognizer(showGestureRecognizer)

             let hideGestureRecognizer:UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleSwipe:")
        hideGestureRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left
        originView!.addGestureRecognizer(hideGestureRecognizer)
    }
}
```

I HAVE IMPLEMENTED MORE METHODS BELOW BUT ERRORS ARE IN THESE LINES OF CODE

Comment: Perhaps this is an obvious error (ios is not my domain) but typically some more explaination often makes it easier to people to help you.

Comment: [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qaLiZgUK2T0]    ----This is the youtube link through which i am trying to clear a blurry side menu. i am new to iOS programming please help !.Thanks In  Advance

Comment: 1. Please edit your question to fix the code formatting. 2. Include explaination in the question, not just add a link to the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not necessary to override init(). Or you declare the `init(sourceView:UIView, menuItems:Array<String>)` as convenience like below:

```
convenience init(sourceView:UIView, menuItems:Array<String>) {
           super.init()
           self.init() // don't forget calling self.init
           originView = sourceView
           sideBarTableViewController.tableData = menuItems
           animator = UIDynamicAnimator(referenceView: originView!)
           setupSideBar()
```